# Parse Objects not appearing in Dashboard

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-server

I have followed multiple tutorials and have had no luck. When I run the app no objects show up on the parse server. I am not sure if there is something wrong with the code, here it is:

```
package com.example.patri.index;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseObject;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .applicationId("MyAppId")
            .server("http://myserver/parse")
            .build()
        );

        ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
        testObject.put("foo", "bar");
        testObject.saveInBackground();
    }
}
```

Comment: Parse is deprecated - https://www.parse.com/migration

Comment: I'm talking about Parse Server. I know Parse is deprecated. @JaredBurrows

Comment: Have you completed the server side setup ?

Comment: How / where did you add the API keys to your android project?

Comment: I am new to programming but I don't think the tutorial had anything to do with API keys. If your talking about the ID of the server I am sure I did that part correctly.

Comment: My friend has, he's working on an apple device but parse should work with both. @vishnu narayanan